# How to setup autocomplete for system packages

Tags: oracle, ide, datagrip

friends!
I use Jetbrains DataGrip 2017.3.7 Build #DB-173.4674.7, built on February 27, 2018
for oracle pl sql develop. But I cant to setup autocomplete for system packages, as DBMS* and others.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add SYS and SYSTEM to the database tree.
And wai a little bit :)

[image: System schemas]